# I want to develop a talk program using python

Tags: python, nlp, text-to-speech, pyttsx3, gtts

and iam looking for  libraries that supports Arabic-SA (Saudi Arabia) language  any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Google 'Voice Recognition Python Saudi Arabia'. I have looked through several results. This one looks most promising: https://www.nobleprog-ksa.com/cc/sphynx.